# Angular loading css files taking time and throw error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular-seed starter project and I wanted to load CSS files according to the language selected by user. I have 2 files for each css file. I have a `ltr-bootstrap.css` to load everything for English and `rtl-bootstrap.css` to load rtl version.

To solve this problem. I added a controller in the HTML so that I can control the user selected language and change file names. Here is the code:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" dir="{{dir}}" ng-controller="HeadController">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Angular seed</title>

    <!-- For browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/{{rtl}}bootstrap.css">

    <!-- custom style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/{{rtl}}style.css">


</head>
<body>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/view1">view1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/view2">view2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- In production use:
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
    -->

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-css/angular-css.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
    <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>

    <script src="dist/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.view1',
    'myApp.view2'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!#');

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]).
controller('HeadController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rtl = 'rtl-';
    $scope.dir = 'rtl';
});
```

Everything works fine and `rtl-bootstrap` is being loaded but it is taking time. Because as soon as I logon to `localhot:8000`, it tries to load the css files and then angular is being loaded so it throws an error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/dist/bootstrap/css/%7B%7Brtl%7D%7Dbootstrap.css 
localhost/:23 Not Found
GET http://localhost:8000/dist/css/%7B%7Brtl%7D%7Dstyle.css Not Found
```

Comment: Just as an advise: try Pascal Precht's https://angular-translate.github.io/ ...

Comment: @Marco|S, thanks for the advice mate. I would use it but we need right to left for arabic language and i am using bootstrap and it doesn't support rtl. We converted it using gul-css-flip to make it work.

Comment: I see... Sorry, I never tought about CSS needing RTL support, too... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular  braces  are included in the url thats the reason for %7b in the url, use the ngHref directive

```
 ng-href="css/{{rtl}}bootstrap.css"
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine :-)

Answer (score -1):

Better use `ng-href` that will ultimately render as `href` attribute but only if the expression inside the `ng-href` are resolved fully.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="css/{{rtl}}bootstrap.css">
```

This also helps in SEO. The crawlers won't see the `ng-href` neither the `href` attribute so no additional request to your server will be made by the web crawlers.